beamer: tikz for a custom environment used in place of themes
I used tikz to make an environment in beamer to be used in place of a theme. The problem is that I'm using the overlay, remember picture option and it requires running latex/lualatex twice every time. Since the elements for which tikz is used are simple there might be alternatives to tikz. If anybody could provide an alternative to tikz here ...?
By setting tmargin to the height of the top decorative rule, the vertical centering is adjusted relatively to the white part of the slide.
I'm trying to get a light shading effect on the bottom and right edges of that top rule... so if anyboby can suggestion ...?
here is the code:
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\newlength{\slw}\setlength{\slw}{160mm}
\newlength{\slh}\setlength{\slh}{90mm}
\newlength{\topH}\setlength{\topH}{11mm}
\geometry{verbose,papersize={\slw,\slh},tmargin=\topH}

\usepackage{tikz,fontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{entete}{HTML}{80e3ff}
\definecolor{bleufon}{HTML}{000090}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=bleufon}
\newlength{\rulewid}\setlength{\rulewid}{.6\slw}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{diap}{ m +b }
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \fill[preaction={fill=black!20,transform canvas={shift={(2pt,-2pt)}}}]
      [fill=entete]
      (current page.north west)   -- ++(\rulewid,0) [rounded corners=.5\topH]
    -- ++(0,-\topH) [sharp corners] -- ++(-\rulewid,0) 
    -- cycle;

    \node at (current page.north west)
      [shift={($ (.3,-.5\topH) + (1pt,-1pt) $)},
       anchor=west,font=\LARGEr,black!30] {#1};
    \node at (current page.north west)
      [shift={(.3,-.5\topH)},anchor=west,font=\LARGEr,bleufon] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  { #2 } {}
  
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \begin{diap}{title}
    content
  \end{diap}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


You don't need to compile twice every time. As long as you don't delete the auxiliary files, compile twice at the start and in the future compiling once will be enough.

Your code does not compile.

Can you please choose a title which will help future users with the same problem to find your question?

now it should be compilable

Your code does not compile. Neither \enttH nor \rulewidth are defined. Please test your example code before posting questions!
That being said:

I wouldn't manually mess with the geometry settings. Beamer is very well capable to change the aspect ratio of the slides and calculate the height of the headline.

Instead of creating a new environment inside of your frames, I would adjust the frametitle template.

You don't need to compile twice every time. As long as you don't delete the auxiliary files, compile twice at the start and in the future compiling once will be enough. Also many other elements in latex/beamer require two compilations initially, e.g. the toc, cross references, the total frame number ... chances are you'll anyway need multiple compilations.

You can avoid the second compilation altogether if you don't use the remember picture, overlay options. The frametitle is anyway at the top of the page.

TikZ offers many different shadows. Using them seems easier than your preaction. To recreate your effect, a drop shadow probably comes closest.

I wouldn't use the fontsize package if you don't also use a scalable font.


\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newlength{\topH}\setlength{\topH}{11mm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{entete}{HTML}{80e3ff}
\definecolor{bleufon}{HTML}{000090}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=bleufon}
\newlength{\rulewidth}\setlength{\rulewidth}{.6\paperwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \nointerlineskip%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \vskip-1mm%
  \hskip-\beamer@leftmargin%
  \hskip-1mm%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[drop shadow,fill=entete] (0,0)   -- ++(\rulewidth,0) [rounded corners=.5\topH] -- ++(0,-\topH) [sharp corners] -- ++(-\rulewidth,0) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,0) [shift={($ (.3,-.5\topH) + (1pt,-1pt) $)}, anchor=west,font=\LARGE,black!30] {\insertframetitle};
    \node at (0,0)     [shift={(.3,-.5\topH)},anchor=west,font=\LARGE,bleufon] {\insertframetitle};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
    content content content content content content content content
  \end{frame}
  
  \begin{frame}
    content content content content content content content content
  \end{frame}  
\end{document}




avoid things like "Please test your example code before posting questions!".  Keep it for abusive behaviours, otherwise it sounds uncivilised.

@user1850133 It is uncivilised to not test your code before posting.

put your head out of computers and breathe worldly life from time to time...

the .aux file will be there only if the previous compilation went fine. Otherwise it must backed up and restored before running the engine.

@user1850133 If the previous compilation didn't went fine, you should anyway compile two times as the auxiliary files might have been corrupted. Nothing really tikz specific.
